# fgrosse/phpasn1 2.0.1 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system

Tags: php, composer-php, phpasn1

Im running a Linux Centos7 VPS.  Before today, I had been running PHP 7.0.x with
PHPASN1 and Jose PHP packages to use with my iOS HTTP2 APNS server.  Everything has been working fine for about a year.

I noticed that I was not getting my APN's anymore and found that they were
failing in the PHPASN1 package, so I decided to update both packages with composer.  Things appeared to install fine, but after various things not working (all of which I don't know at this point as Ive been through many iterations today), Im now at this point:

```
php composer.phar update
```

I get the following message:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - fgrosse/phpasn1 2.0.1 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
    - fgrosse/phpasn1 2.0.1 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for fgrosse/phpasn1 v2.0.1 -> satisfiable by fgrosse/phpasn1[2.0.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

AFAIK, I already have ext-gmp installed:

```
rpm -qa | grep gmp

gmp-devel-6.0.0-15.el7.x86_64
gmp-6.0.0-15.el7.x86_64
```

I compile Apache 2.4.x and PHP 7.0.x manually when updates become available and Im
up to date on both as of today.  I compile PHP with the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php7029 --with-apxs2=/opt/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysqli --enable-shared --enable-session --enable-libxml --enable-pcntl --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvsem --with-openssl --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --enable-mbstring
 --with-config-file-path=/etc
```

If I try to run my PHP script that pushes an APNS I get the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function FG\ASN1\Universal\gmp_init() in /http_src/navee/apns/jwt/vendor/fgrosse/phpasn1/lib/ASN1/Universal/Integer.php:95
Stack trace:
#0 /http_src/navee/apns/jwt/vendor/fgrosse/phpasn1/lib/ASN1/ASNObject.php(222): FG\ASN1\Universal\Integer::fromBinary('0\x81\x93\x02\x01\x000\x13\x06\x07*\x86H\xCE=...', 5)
#1 /http_src/navee/apns/jwt/vendor/fgrosse/phpasn1/lib/ASN1/Construct.php(165): FG\ASN1\ASNObject::fromBinary('0\x81\x93\x02\x01\x000\x13\x06\x07*\x86H\xCE=...', 5)
#2 /http_src/navee/apns/jwt/vendor/fgrosse/phpasn1/lib/ASN1/ASNObject.php(232): FG\ASN1\Construct::fromBinary('0\x81\x93\x02\x01\x000\x13\x06\x07*\x86H\xCE=...', 5)
#3 /http_src/navee/apns/jwt/vendor/spomky-labs/jose/src/KeyConverter/ECKey.php(67): FG\ASN1\ASNObject::fromBinary('0\x81\x93\x02\x01\x000\x13\x06\x07*\x86H\xCE=...')
#4 /http_src/navee/apns/jwt/vendor/spomky-labs/jose/src/KeyConverter/ECKey.php(49): Jose\KeyConverter\ECKey->loadPEM('0\x81\x93\x02\x01\x000\x13\x06\x07*\x86H\xCE=...')
#5 /http_src/nav in /http_src/navee/apns/jwt/vendor/fgrosse/phpasn1/lib/ASN1/Universal/Integer.php on line 95
```

After spending half of today trying to figure this out with no luck, Im posting here in case someone can tell me what to check or how to fix this.
Im not very familiar with composer.phar, just the basics but it seems that there's a path somewhere thats not setup correctly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you install the PHP module for GMP? What does `php -m | grep gmp` tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Nico for that hint.  I don't know how it happened, but my PHP configuration line I always use had removed **--with-gmp=** and **--with-curl=** values.  My curl didn't work once the ext-gmp issue was resolved as well.  Once I fixed that and re-installed, everything worked just fine.  Thanks again!